# When neural network loss is descending but the accuracy is not increased?

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, backpropagation, perceptron

I implement a batch-based back-propagation algorithm for a neural network with one hidden layer and sigmoid activation function. The output layer is one-hot Sigmoid layer. The net of first layer is z1. After apply sigmoid it becomes a1.  similarly, we have z2 and a2 for the second layer.

The back-propagation process is like this:

```
x, y = train_data, train_target
for i in range(0, num_passes):
    # call
    z1, a1, z2, a2 = predict(current_model, x)

    # recall
    derv_out2 = (y - a2) * (a2 * (1 - a2))
    delta2 = np.matmul(np.transpose(a1), derv_out2) / train_size
    dw2 = delta2 + reg_lambda * w2
    db2 = np.mean(b2 * derv_out2, 0)

    derv_out1 = a1 * np.reshape(np.sum(delta2 * w2, 1), [1, a1.shape[1]])
    delta1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(x), derv_out1) / train_size
    dw1 = delta1 + reg_lambda * w1
    db1 = np.mean(b1 * derv_out1, 0)

    # gradient descent parameter update
    w1 += learning_rate * dw1
    b1 += learning_rate * db1
    w2 += learning_rate * dw2
    b2 += learning_rate * db2

    # assign new parameters to the model
    current_model = {'w1': w1, 'b1': b1, 'w2': w2, 'b2': b2}
```

complete code file: [link](https://github.com/MohsenIT/MLP_simple/blob/master/q1_mnist.py)

The loss of the above algorithms is decreasing, but accuracy of classification is about random choice. What is the problem?

Comment: Your accuracy metric is a simple av(sum(1 or 0)) but the loss is based on a comparison of the full output vector to it's desired value.  As you run the net the output vector difference can get smaller without the true/false accuracy test getting better.  If simplify your loss to be..

Comment: `np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(output - target)))` and set `learning_rate = 1.0`, you can see both the accuracy and loss bottom-out in just a few iterations and don't change much.  The bigger issue here is that you have an error in your delta calculations somewhere that is giving you bad updates. (sorry about multiple comments here - hit enter on accident)

Comment: For fun I replaced you optimization code/model with an equivalent in Keras.  Using SDG optimization and a batch size of 50,000 as you are, it didn't optimize (at least not in a reasonable time).  If I switched the batch size to 128 it optimized in a hundred epochs or so.  If I switched the optimizer to RMSProp (128 batch) it was optimized reasonably well after the first epoch.  You may not have a powerful enough optimization algorithm to deal with the data.  If you have to do it this way I'd try a smaller batch size and a LOT of iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @bivouac0 comment, I try to tune learning rate.
I found that learning rate of 0.1 or 0.01 is very low for elementary steps (causes long learning time). Afterward I implement adaptive approach to tune learning rate (increase the rate when loss is descending and decrease when ascending). Using this approach the accuracy improved significantly.